# magento error logs Error log record number: 1173359093956

Tags: magento2

I am having following error in Magento 2.3.0. After clicking on save product.

> {"0":"Notice: Undefined variable: redirectBack in
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/app/code/Magebay/Marketplace/Controller/Product/Save.php
>   on line 175","1":"#0
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/app/code/Magebay/Marketplace/Controller/Product/Save.php(175):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined
>   varia...', '/home/booking24...', 175, Array)\n#1
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/generated/code/Magebay/Marketplace/Controller/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save->execute()\n#2
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save\Interceptor->execute()\n#3
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/app/code/Magebay/Marketplace/Controller/Product/Account.php(48):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#4
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Account->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#5
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#6
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#7
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/generated/code/Magebay/Marketplace/Controller/Product/Save/Interceptor.php(52):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#8
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(159):
>   Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#9
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(99):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http),
>   Object(Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save\Interceptor))\n#10
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#11
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#12
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#13
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#14
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#15
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#17
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#18
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#19
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#20
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#21
>   /home/booking24/public_html/testing/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#22
>   {main}","url":"/marketplace/product/save/set/4/type/booking/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: you have issue at Magebay_MarketPlace.

Comment: Error is from Magebay\Marketplace\Controller\Product\Save.php on line 175. Please check there

Comment: if ($redirectBack === 'draft') {
                $resultRedirect->setPath('marketplace/seller/myProducts');
            } elseif ($redirectBack === 'new') {
                $resultRedirect->setPath(
                    'marketplace/*/create',
                    ['set' => $productAttributeSetId, 'type' => $productTypeId]
                );

Comment: above lines is in Save.php

Comment: Is this variable declared please check it else check this variable usage $redirectBack

Comment: There is a flaw with Magento module. After entering quantity it got fixed.